# How to convert date time format in SQL Server like '2017-03-04 10:07:03.490' to date format which is seperated by - like '2-11-2016'

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am tying to make date comparison with the query

```
select * 
from dbo.OH_Case   
where dbo.OH_Case.CreatedDate between Convert(varchar(30),'24/04/2017', 102)  
                                  and Convert(varchar(30),'01/05/2017', 102)
```

but it throws this error:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

My application passes data in '01/05/2017' format and the date information in SQL Server is stored in '2017-03-04 10:07:03.490' format. What should I do to make both of these in same format which allows comparison?

Comment: If `CreatedDate` is of datetime datatype, you should compare it with other datetime's, not varchar's. Also, [Beware of between when comparing dates](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

Comment: Forget appearance.  What is the datatype of oh_Case.CreatedDate?

Comment: This might help you https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: `YYYY-MM-DD...` is ISO format and recommended for storage and comparison. The other `01/05/2017` is specific to region and is only for displaying, not for software/system needs.

Comment: @DanBracuk its of date time type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're converting a string literal to a `varchar`.  Convert it to a `datetime` instead.

Second, you're passing in `24/04/2017`, but [date format 102](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) is `yyyy.mm.dd`.  Try date format 103 for `dd/mm/yyyy`:

```
convert(datetime, '24/04/2017', 103)
```

Comment: Using a statement like SET Language German (and you can choose the language that would interpret your date values in the right way) can also help a great deal. Then SQL will know how to interpret your date values and not mess up months and days.

Answer (score 0):

Here `dbo.OH_Case.CreatedDate` is of data type Datetime and you have to convert your values in Datetime format for filter.
convert columns in Datetime format and format will be same for all. In your case, convert values in Datetime instead of Varchar and it will work fine.

```
select * from 
dbo.OH_Case   
where dbo.OH_Case.CreatedDate between  cast('24/04/2017' as datetime)  and
cast('01/05/2017' as datetime)
```

**Updates:**

Siddharth, I have checked you date values and figured out that issue is in date "24/04/2017". This format is for "MM/dd/yyyy". and 24 is passed as month which is not valid. Therefore it is throwing exception. I have updated result 
to handle such exceptions.

```
select * from 
dbo.OH_Case   
where dbo.OH_Case.CreatedDate between  convert(datetime, '24/04/2017', 103)  and
convert(datetime, '01/05/2017', 103)
```

Comment: Unfortunately , it throws the same error mentioned in question

Comment: what is the data type of column dbo.OH_Case.CreatedDate?

Answer (score 0):

Here dbo.OH_Case.CreatedDate is of data type Datetime and you have to convert your values in Datetime format for filter. convert columns in Datetime format and format will be same for all. In your case, convert values in Datetime instead of Varchar and it will work fine.

```
select * from dbo.OH_Case format(where dbo.OH_Case.CreatedDate, 'dd/mm/yyyy') as CreatedDate
```